# Count pdo incorrect with clause WHERE and Join

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a query like this :

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS nbOfRec, 
    m1.FRN_ID, m1.FRN_NOM, m1.FRN_RGN_ID, m1.FRN_TYPE_ENTREE, m1.FRN_MIN_FACT 
    FROM produits 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fournisseur AS m1 ON (m1.FRN_ID=produits.PRD_FRN_ID) 
    WHERE FRN_TYPE_ENTREE LIKE '%%'
```

In PHP,

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS nbOfRec,
m1.FRN_ID, m1.FRN_NOM, m1.FRN_RGN_ID, m1.FRN_TYPE_ENTREE, m1.FRN_MIN_FACT
FROM produits 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fournisseur AS m1 ON (m1.FRN_ID=produits.PRD_FRN_ID)
$sql_where"; 
$result = $db->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$nb_records = $result->fetchColumn(0);
```

If i delete $sql_where which contain `"FRN_TYPE_ENTREE LIKE '%$type_entree%'";` i'm getting 943 results.

If i keep the sql_where with a empty result (for $type_entree) i'm getting 825 results... What's wrong ?

My produits table contain 943 results.

Comment: Some of you DB values may have a space before or after them e.g. " JOHN " would search like  LIKE % $value % where "JOHN" would be LIKE %$value%

Comment: Yes it was a problem with my db sorry

Comment: No problem its easy done